# SASS inverse select of input types

Tags: css, sass

I need to apply a class `.invalid` to all input types but email and password

```
input{
   &[type="everything but email and password"]
   .invalid{
     //styles
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS `:not()`  selector you can achieve it.

```
input{
   &:not([type="email"]):not([type="password"]) {
     .invalid{
       //styles
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was it.  I voted to accept the answer but it's not being displayed because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @MegaMan You can accept the answer. You cannot upvote the answer due your low reputation. But **you must accept always the correct answer**, clicking in the check below the votes system. Thank you!